# for statement in a while loop not working?

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A loop of your own</title>
        <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    //Add while loop below
    $hello = true;
    while($hello = true):
    {
        echo "Loop is runnin";
        for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++)
        {
            $hello = false;
        }
    }
    endwhile
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

My error is: infinite loop.

How can I fix this? I'm practising;-)

I want a for loop within a while loop, code must say 3 times "Loop is running" then make the

variable $hello false.

```
$hello = true;
while($hello == true):
    echo "Loop is runnin";
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
    {
       $hello = false;
    }
endwhile;
```

This is the result,  but if you guys had a sharp eye you would have saw it, the for loop wil only run one time:p Because it will try to set $hello 3x times to false.

But thank you all for answering my question;)

Comment: 1. What is `:` doing after while statement? 2. $hello == true is logical expression, $hello = true is assignment. You need the first.

Comment: @sashkello It's starting an *alternative while syntax*.

Comment: @deceze in that case what are those curly braces doing? ;)

Comment: @deceze It should be either or :)

Comment: @PeeHaa Not much, but they're not in the way either. It's just a superfluous group.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a mistake, it's just weird looking...

Comment: Yeah. superfluous meaning it *does*  get in the way imo. It's like wrapping blocks in `{{{}}}` for code folding

Comment: to me, all the alternative syntax loops and branches are a true WTF. why would you uver use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this.

```
$hello = 0;

while($hello < 3):

    echo "Loop is runnin";
    $hello++;
endwhile;
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted, but it works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try to do like this:

```
while($hello == true)
{
    echo "Loop is runnin";
    for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++)
    {
        $hello = false;
    }
}
endwhile;
```

You need to use `==` instead of `=` for comparison as well as adding `;` after your `endwhile`

---

If you only want to echo `Loop is running` 3 times, you need to change:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++)
```

to:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
```

or:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
```

Comment: Spot the difference...?

Comment: @deceze == instead of =

Comment: Why not point that out specifically?

Comment: @deceze and the `;` after `endwhile`

Comment: btw its still not the desired result of the first post. he want get 3x  loop is running. so in real the echo should be inside the second loop. sense or nonsense.... whatever :) *edit -> $i should also start at 1 for 3x output... now its looping 4 times

Comment: @KURN yes it should be `$i < 3`

Comment: $hello = true;
    while($hello == true):
        echo "Loop is runnin";
        for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
        {
           $hello = false;
        }
    endwhile;

This is the result,  but if you guys had a sharp eye you would have saw it, the for loop wil only run one time:p Because it will try to set $hello 3x times to false.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) for syntax, you need a ';' after your endwhile. Because you've use a colon after your while statement, you shouldn't enclose the while loop code within curly brackets.  Try;

```
   $hello = true;
    while($hello = true):

        echo "Loop is runnin";
        for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++)
        {
            $hello = false;
        }

    endwhile;
```